Errors Unable to find method ''com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'
I tried syncing gms:google-services:4.4.1 with tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 as an upgrade but was receiving the following error message. Initially, I was using gms:google-services:4.3.15 with tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 and with no issues. What could be the solution to this problem?

Can you share your build.gradle files (project and application)?

I tried posting both gradles but it says "too long by 2000 characters."

After I changed the grandle-wrapper version to gradle-8.7-bin.zip, it is solved. And then we have to adjust to latest version of kotlin and build grandle. Like this,
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10' // Ensure this is a valid Kotlin version
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
